# Create a blank text file from within a function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, text

I wnat to create a function:

```
function[check]=createFile(filename, matrix)
```

Where I create a blank text file with the name 'filename'.
Where later in the function inputs from 'matrix' can be put in and stored.

2 question:
1)How do I create just a blank .txt file?

2)I've had some problem with this in somewhat simular functions, but is there an easy way to get rid of the need to write apostrophes in the arguments when calling the function?(i.e: createFile(name,matrix) instead of createFile('name',matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create the text file just use:

`fid = fopen('filename.txt','w')`

and there is no way to avoid the apostrophies `'filename.txt'` - as matlab would try to call a function `filename.txt` which it wouldn't find.

for your function you can use

```
function  [check] = createFile(filename, matrix)

% filename contains string!    

fid = fopen(filename,'w')`

if exist('fid')
    check = true;
else
    check = false;
end

... write your matrix to file.


end
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2) but is there an easy way to get rid of the need to write apostrophes in the arguments when calling the function?(i.e: createFile(name,matrix) instead of createFile('name',matrix)

Yes: you can type

```
createFile name matrix
```

after you have included this in createFile.m:

```
function createFile(name,matrix)
matrix=evalin('caller',matrix);
```